# Beginner question about measuring current using digital multimeter

Tags: multimeter, current-measurement

I have a beginner question about using multimeter to measure a current. I have dc motor, attached to 2 x AAA batteries. 
Which reading I should use, 200 m under DCA or 2000 mA?
On 200 m, the current reads 15
On 2000 mA, the current reads 150.

Which one is the correct way of measuring the current?
For batteries current, do you use 200m or 2000mA?

[image]

Comment: Please add the position of the decimal point to the numbers in your question. I assume it is something like .15 or 0.15 in the 2000 mA range and 150 in the 200 mA range. Note that 0.15 A = 150 mA.

Comment: @user4185, the 400m is intended as 400mA and is written that way for space. Same with all of the A measurements.

Comment: Thanks guys. on 2000mA it reads = 120. on 200mA it reads = 12. on 20mA it reads = 1.2. on 2000u it reads = 0. So what's the correct current?

Comment: @zebonaut: No decimal point. Only when I see to 20mA, it shows 1.2

Comment: Related to precision, not exactly what is being asked though: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13313/different-current-readings-with-a-multimeter-between-the-200-ma-and-the-10-a-slot

Comment: Based off of all of the answers given so far, this question is a duplicate of the question I linked to. I don't think that is the issue he is having though. He is trying to figure out why there is a 0 missing when he switches ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General rule for measuring currents with multimeters:

- Start with the highest range available (in you case: 2000 mA).
- If you read a value below the next lower range (in your case: 200 mA), change to this lower range.
- If the value is below the next available lower range, again, go one step down.
- ...

Here's [a very good article by Analog Devices' applications engineer James M. Bryant about using standard multimeters](http://jbryant.eu/pages/DMM.htm) written for beginners with much attention to details.

Comment: Thanks guys. on 2000mA it reads = 120. on 200mA it reads = 12. on 20mA it reads = 1.2. on 2000u it reads = 0. So what's the correct current?

Comment: This is weird. If it reads 120 on 2000mA, I would expect 120.0 on 200 mA and Overload (or something like 1.___) on 20 mA. Are there different plugs for the 2000 mA range and, respectively, the lower ranges?

Comment: you are right! Thanks! It has anohter plug. the other plug is for 200mA Max (Fused). So when I measured it using 200m, it gave me consistent reading. When I turned it to 20m, it gave me 1. Which is correct.

Comment: I want to add, the reading 2000ma is the correct reading. So I motor is 150mA.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the 2A range requires plugging the leads into a different jack than the other ranges.

Both ranges should give you the same number.  Higher current ranges have lower shunt resistances, lower burden voltage, greater accuracy, less precision.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the lowest possible range. If you start at the 2000 mA range and it shows a value less than 200 mA, switch to the 200 mA range. But the reading should be the same for both ranges. Be sure you use the right jacks for each range.

Comment: Always use the lowest - yes.  However always 'start' with the highest.

Comment: Thanks guys. on 2000mA it reads = 120. on 200mA it reads = 12. on 20mA it reads = 1.2. on 2000u it reads = 0. So what's the correct current?